# Source code for interpolation using a known set of random points in an area of land

Tags: c#, interpolation

In a fixed area of land random points with their values are generated. I need to get a heat map for this area of land showing the variations using those known point values. 
I have found that mostly IDW and Kriging are amongst the interpolation algorithms which are used to do this job. As I don't have the relevant background, I find these pretty difficult to understand and implement in code. 
The language C# is going to be used to implement the algorithm. So, are there any source code available with appropriate documentation to help understand it, so that it could be easily re-written/modified for this purpose?